# how to intercept __fork() in GNU C standard library?

Tags: ld-preload

I look at the source of GNU C standard library and I see that the implementation of `system` function calls `__fork()`.  I need to intercept that call with my own wrapper for `__fork` and the `LD_PRELOAD` technique.

I think I know how to use `LD_PRELOAD` because:

1. If I call `__fork()` myself in my application, it is intercepted correctly.  So that means, one is able to intercept `__fork()` in principle.
2. If I change `__fork()` to `fork()` in the standard library implementation of `system()` and recompile standard library and use that, then `fork()` is intercepted.

However, `__fork()` in standard library, is not intercepted - my wrapper is not called.

Why??

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, `__fork` is a synonym for `__libc_fork` which does a fork system call directly. `fork` is a weak symbol that refers to the same thing. Overriding any of these functions will work if some other shared library is calling that particular function.

```
$ readelf -Wa /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep b84c0
    42: 00000000000b84c0   784 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __libc_fork@@GLIBC_PRIVATE
    80: 00000000000b84c0   784 FUNC    GLOBAL DEFAULT   13 __fork@@GLIBC_2.2.5
   408: 00000000000b84c0   784 FUNC    WEAK   DEFAULT   13 fork@@GLIBC_2.2.5
```

However, within libc itself, the linker knows that `__fork` is located inside the same library and it opts to not go through the [PLT](https://www.technovelty.org/linux/plt-and-got-the-key-to-code-sharing-and-dynamic-libraries.html) to reach that function. It just emits a direct call instruction. This is a common optimization for GCC to do when a module calls a static function, or when a library calls one of its own functions. See below (the call would be to `__fork@plt` if it went through the PLT):

```
$ objdump -d /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 | grep __fork | head -n 4
   6a074:   e8 47 e4 04 00          callq  b84c0 <__fork@@GLIBC_2.2.5>
00000000000b84c0 <__fork@@GLIBC_2.2.5>:
   b84da:   74 5c                   je     b8538 <__fork@@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x78>
   b84e1:   74 ed                   je     b84d0 <__fork@@GLIBC_2.2.5+0x10>
```

When you changed libc to use fork() internally, it was calling a *weak symbol*, and those may be [overridden by the user](http://www.cs.virginia.edu/~wh5a/blog/The%20weak%20attribute%20of%20gcc.html). Thus the linker has no choice but to emit a call that goes through the PLT. This means that you can actually overload it with `LD_PRELOAD`.

In general, it's not going to be easy to hijack fork like this. Functions can always invoke a fork system call directly and there is no way to intercept that. You might be interested in [`pthread_atfork`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/pthread_atfork) if your code uses pthreads. This adds functions to the `__fork_handlers` array inside glibc. Unfortunately that array is marked as protected and the symbol cannot be accessed directly.

Comment: By the way, to debug this sort of thing it's helpful to set `LD_BIND_NOW=1` and single-step in GDB, watching exactly which symbols get called.